# Commutation overlap symmetry

Tags: diodes, inductance, bridge-rectifier, commutation

Let's say we have three phase diode (ignore SCR in the picture) rectifier:

[image: img1]

With no source inductance, diodes are conducting at following angles:

Diode 1: 30º < X < 150º
Diode 4: 210º < X < 330º

Diode 3: 150º < X < 270º
Diode 6: 330º < X < 450º (= -90º)

Diode 5: 270º < X < 390º (= -30º)
Diode 2: 90º < X < 210º

Adding source inductance causes each of the diodes to conduct more than 120º per cycle, causing them to overlap:

[image: img2]

QUESTION: Let's assume we add the exact amount of source inductance so that each of the diodes conducts 140º per cycle. Does now diode D1 conduct between 20º and 160º, so the extra +20º degrees split symmetrically, +10º at the beginning and +10º at the end?

---

Ref: [Commutation overlap angle](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337941/commutation-overlap-angle).

Comment: Already addressed in your comment to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337941/commutation-overlap-angle/337943?noredirect=1#comment808421_337943.

Comment: True. The way I understand it, the answer to this particular question is - not symmetrical?